# Probability that the difference between two numbers is at least $m$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $m<n$. Two different numbers (from $1,2,\dots n$) are chosen. Find the probability that the difference between the first number and the second is not less than $m$.

Analytically, I have found that the answer is $\frac{(n-m+1)(n-m)}{2n(n-1)}$, which is the correct answer.

I am also trying to solve the problem geometrically, but I get a different answer. On the coordinate plane, we need to sum the areas of two right triangles, which is $(n-m)^2$. This should be divided by the area of the $n \times n$ square, but this yields a wrong answer.

Where am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: The numbers have to be natural numbers. What you are assuming in solving it geometrically is that they are real numbers. That's why you're getting a wrong answer.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how do I consider only natural numbers using the geometric approach?

Comment: Count the points in the two triangles

Comment: One more detail I would like to clarify. When it is specified that the difference should be $\geq m$ between the first number and the second one, there is actually just one triangle, whereas there would be such triangles of the same area if the difference is supposed to be $|x-y|$?